# Bigquery - Silent Login

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using big Query command line. when I use gcloud auth login it asks for login. and when for Unix I need to get Authorization Code.

Is there any way where I can put credentials somewhere (With password) so that I don't have to do it manually? I am trying to get it automated. I can use Secret Key for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a service account file to authenticate:

```
bq --service_account=someServiceAccount.gserviceaccount.com \ 
   --service_account_credential_file=~/clok_cred.txt \
   --service_account_private_key_file=/somekeyFile.p12 \
   --project_id=formal-cascade-571 \
   query "select * from dw_test.clokTest"
```

See also "[How to get gcloud auth activate-service-account persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066461/how-to-get-gcloud-auth-activate-service-account-persist)".

Docs: https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account